# Itext-5.5.3 Is returning long version name while applying digital signature on the pdf

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext

Stack trace of exception thrown from itext :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The name 'iText® 5.5.3 ©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version)' is too long (128 characters).
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.<init>(PdfName.java:2417)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.<init>(PdfName.java:2403)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfSignatureAppDictionary.setSignatureCreator(PdfSignatureAppDictionary.java:67)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfSignatureBuildProperties.setSignatureCreator(PdfSignatureBuildProperties.java:68)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignature.setSignatureCreator(PdfSignature.java:102)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:133)
    at com.newgen.omni.oms.output.PDFOperations.addDigitalSignature(PDFOperations.java:823)
```

Comment: Do you understand what AGPL stands for? Is your project an open source project, or are you developing a closed source application?

Comment: That wasn't the question. Don't you think that `iText® 5.5.3 ©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version) (AGPL-version)` is a bit too long? The question is more "why do you need to repeat AGPL 6 times? Shouldn't `iText® 5.5.3 ©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)` be enough?

Comment: It's open Source, Please suggest the solution @BrunoLowagie
Yes i under the term AGPL but why is it getting repeated 4 times.

Comment: Please share the URL where I can download your full project licensed as AGPL.

Comment: Not fully developed yet.